# MVC 5 WF4.5 : Dynamic View select in running workflow

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, workflow-foundation

I am now contemplating on a creating few workflows using WF4.5 MVC 5. Most of these workflows are human workflows (state based), long but quite straight forward. However some of them require me to show a runtime decided view (or pre-configured view based on certain rules) view when a state has been transitioned

For e.g.

```
Step 1: Customer1 drafts a loan request (LoanView)
Step 2: Teller1 (with review permissions) reviews and submits this request (LoanView)
Step 3: Manager1 (with Bank profile) Reviews the request (LoanView)
Step 3a: Manager1 checks few options for e.g. RequestCreditScore
```

> ```
> Step 3b: Can Manager1 choose a *view* available in the project as a next step(s)?
> ```

```
Step 4: UnderWriter1 generates Credit Score, and adds comments (CreditScoreView)
Step 5: OtherUsers review information based on the *views* chosen by Manager1
```

Please can someone help me point in the right direction, the idea here is under **Customer** folder there are many views (and more will be added over time). In step 3b I am hoping the Manager can choose all the views required to be re-certified for e.g. `LoanCommitments`, `Insurance`, `MonthlySpendAnalysis` etc. All these views could possibly implement a common contract like `IWorkflowableView`  (I havent thought/couldnt think, about the definition of the view yet, but I am looking for pointers from SO)

Do let me know if I have missed the obvious

Comment: You might need to explore the "Virtual Path Providers" option to dynamically load and manipulate the views from the database based on some condition. The penalty is "Performance"...

Comment: if I am willing to bite the bullet on performance, could you explain how to do this please, with an example.